# Email me when front posting or update post

Tags: wp-mail

In my site, users can submit post at front-end. And I want to be informed by email when users submit or update post.

I searched some codes about this. I'll use wp_main function.

```
function send_posting_emails($post_id){
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;
    if(get_post_status($post_id) == 'trash')
        return;
    $to  = 'sunbeamlove@naver.com';
    $subject = $post->post_title.'is updated';
    $post = get_post();

    $body = '<h1>'.$post->post_title.'is updated.</h1>';
    if(is_category){
        $category = get_the_category();
        $body .= '<h2>카테고리: <em>'.$category[0]->cat_name .'</em></h2>';
    }
    $body .= '<h3>포스팅날짜: '.$post->post_date.'</h3>';        
    $body .= '<p>URL: ' . get_permalink($post_id) . ' or</p>';

    if(did_action('post_updated') == 1){
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }
}

add_action('post_updated', 'send_posting_emails');
```

Above codes are set to be sent email when post is published I guess. 
In my site, front-posting is submitted as 'draft'. So, this email-alarm doesn't work at front-posting.

Can I get some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'post_updated' for your hook, you might try 'save_post' or 'wp_insert_post'